# single (unique) results in sql query result

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm really stuck:

A little background: I've build a website with a database with multiple tables.
It is about minerals that have fluorescense under different types of UV light (long wave, medium wave and short wave, LW, MW and SW)
The website is working fine, however, with a little bit too much results.

I have a table with all the details of the minierals, I have a table where I put the photo's and with those photo's I save what kind of UV is used.
Now I want a query that filters for specific wave lengts; but I get double results since I've multiple photo's with a specific wave length, see yellow marking in example. [19 results instead of 18 results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVND1.png)

How do I get the distinct results? So, in this case, how do I get 18 unique results instead of 19 results as shown?

The query I use right now is

`` SELECT m.korte_naam, m.url_naam, m.mineraal_id, m.opmerking, m.vindplaats_kort, m.gewicht from `mineraal` m, `foto` f where m.mineraal_id = f.mineraal_id and f.lichtbron = 'SW'; ``

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT...` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to select each item once, you can use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.korte_naam, m.url_naam, m.mineraal_id, m.opmerking, m.vindplaats_kort, m.gewicht from `mineraal` m, `foto` f where m.mineraal_id = f.mineraal_id and f.lichtbron = 'SW';
```

If you want not to keep the same record more than once, you need to check before insertion that record hadn't been inserted already.

Comment: It's not the same record, so no unique value (every photo is different, but light source can be LW, MW or SW.

But; indeed; DISTINCT did the trick. I am aware of distinct and used it quite a lot but for testing purposes mostely on one column. And I used it as "SELECT DISTINCT(column_name) from xyz; 
So, I tried distinct with "(" and ")" around column names but that didn't work.

`SELECT DISTINCT m.korte_naam, m.url_naam, m.mineraal_id, m.opmerking, m.vindplaats_kort, m.gewicht from `mineraal` m, `foto` f where m.mineraal_id = f.mineraal_id and f.lichtbron = 'SW';`
worked! Thanks!